# How to correctly propagate the type of a universal reference?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

I have a situation in my codebase where I must implement a generic form of `std::get()` which works for any kind of Tuple-like type. The function accepts a universal reference to a `Tuple` and returns a reference to the `I`th element of the `Tuple`. I don't know how to name the type of the reference. Unfortunately, I'm unable to use an `auto` return type and just let the compiler figure it out.

Here's my first attempt:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class T, class U>
struct propagate_reference
{
  using type = U;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct propagate_reference<T&,U>
{
  using type = typename std::add_lvalue_reference<U>::type;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct propagate_reference<T&&,U>
{
  using type = typename std::add_rvalue_reference<U>::type;
};

template<size_t I, class TupleReference>
struct get_result
{
  using tuple_type = typename std::decay<TupleReference>::type;

  using type = typename propagate_reference<
    TupleReference,
    typename std::tuple_element<I,tuple_type>::type
  >::type;
};

template<size_t I, class Tuple>
typename get_result<I,Tuple&&>::type my_get(Tuple&& t)
{
  return std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

int foo(const std::tuple<int>& t)
{
  return my_get<0>(t);
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Clang rejects this program:

```
$ clang -std=c++11 test_get.cpp 
test_get.cpp:36:10: error: binding of reference to type 'int' to a value of type 'const __tuple_element_t<0UL, tuple<int> >' (aka 'const int') drops qualifiers
  return std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_get.cpp:41:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'my_get<0, const std::tuple<int> &>' requested here
  return my_get<0>(t);
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I suspect the problem is with the way I instantiate `get_result`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you're unable to return auto?

Comment: This is where you need `remove_reference` and not `decay`.

Comment: What exactly does not work with `std::get`?

Comment: What do you exaclty mean by "I cannot use auto"? You have "-std=c++11" - which suggests that you can use `auto` in C++11 way, but not in C++14 way. Do you have any other constraints - some coding standard?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Yes, I have additional constraints. I know that in general return type deduction is possible. I'm interested in understanding why my initial attempt does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) removes cv-qualifiers, and defines the resulting type as the member typedef type. As already TC mentioned in the comments what you need here is [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference):

```
template<size_t I, class TupleReference>
struct get_result
{
  using tuple_type = typename std::remove_reference<TupleReference>::type;

  using type = typename propagate_reference<
    TupleReference,
    typename std::tuple_element<I,tuple_type>::type
  >::type;
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ab222b66b193543)